# Extention of functions in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\omega$ a subset of a domain  $\Omega\in R^n,$ and let $f\in H^2(\omega)\cap H_0^1(\omega)$.

It is known that a function $u\in H_0^1(\omega)$ admits an axtention $U\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Does exist any extention of $f$ to a function $F \in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$?.

Comment: It doesn't seem clear that the function would be able to have two weak derivatives when you extend it by 0. Otherwise, it could not be in $H^1_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a counter-example in $\Omega = (-1,1)$ and $\omega = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$.

Comment: Nice hint. And if $\omega$ was assumed to be a subdomain, something similar can be done in $\mathbb R^n$ ($n>1$) by wrapping $\omega$ around so that it borders itself along a line segment.